# How to access a form.cs file from another folder and load that form at runtime C#

Tags: c#, winforms, directory, subdirectory

To simplify, i WAS making a fake os (an os which is actually an app) and i wanted to make a find file dialog that will find a .cs file and try to load it as a form at runtime

```
void epicFunction(string file)
{
    if (file.EndsWith(".cs"))
    {
       //Load the form as if it was already compiled in
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you try to do? File Form1.cs is source (text) file containing source code for compilator (VisualStudio for example). This file can't be executed or displayed to the user  as form/dialog.

Comment: actually, i already found out how to do this but I want to access a .csproj project and then run the.exe in it but I already found out how to do this by finding where the folder of the app is and then find the .exe file and run it.

Answer (score 0):

if you know .exe folderis very simple.

```
// Use ProcessStartInfo class
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.FileName = "Test.exe";
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

    try
    {
        // Start the process with the info we specified.
        // Call WaitForExit and then the using statement will close.
        using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
        {
            exeProcess.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
    catch
    {
         // Log error.
    }
```

.csproj is a VS file of your solution...